# create specific permutation of a list in python

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I'm trying to write a function that would input a list (of pre-determined length) and output the permutation of that list according to my choice of re-ordering.

For example, suppose I have the list

```
    [1,'a',12,'b','poppy']
```

and I have the permutation

```
    (3,4,5,2,1)
```

Then the function output would be a list with the third element first, the fourth element second, etc

```
    [12,'b','poppy','a',1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l = [1,'a',12,'b','poppy']

def p(l,t):
    return [l[i-1] for i in t]

print(p(l,(3,4,5,2,1)))
[12, 'b', 'poppy', 'a', 1]
```

indexing is 0 based so if you actually wanted to use the indexes for a 5 element list it would be `(2,3,4,1,0)` and  `[l[i] for i in t]`

Comment: This is basically [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098250/in-place-way-to-apply-a-permutation-to-a-list-inverse-of-sorting-by-key) with a -1.  Should I dup-close or not?

Comment: This question is much clearer written than that similar question.

Comment: @DSM, probably 50/50, the OP may have actually also meant to use zero based indexing so that would be an exact dupe then.

Comment: I'm surprised no one proposed an itemgetter-based approach (although that'd need an extra list call).

Comment: @cnrk, no worries, just make sure if you use zero based indexing t remove the -1

Comment: @DSM Ask and ye shall receive :)

Comment: @DSM, I suppose you could  `itemgetter(*(i-1 for i in t))(l)`  without needed a list call

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yeah, but then the output is a tuple, not a list.

Comment: @DSM,  On that note I am going to turn off my computer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `operator.itemgetter`. Since your permutations are for a 1-based list, you'll need to add a dummy element to the front of your list first. (You could subtract one from each element of `p` using a variety of techniques, but it's simpler to just "shift" the list before passing it to the function returned by `itemgetter`.)

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> p = (3,4,5,2,1)
>>> lst = [1,'a',12,'b','poppy']
>>> itemgetter(*p)([None] + lst)
(12, 'b', 'poppy', 'a', 1)
```

Comment: I was going to `itemgetter(*map(lambda x: x-1, t))(l)` but this is better.

Answer (score 0):

The first element of the list is `0`:

```
l = [1,'a',12,'b','poppy']
p = (2,3,4,1,0)
result = []
for i in p:
    result.append(l[i])
```